Fast Fourier Transform of accelerometer data for vibration
I am new at signal processing. I am trying to compute and plot FFT of a given dataset. The dataset corresponds to vibration signals captured using accelerometer.
The problem that I am facing is when I try to take FFT of the data, it does not provide peaks in the data. There are random peaks, I am unable to understand why such random peaks are generating. The code I am using is given below.
output
from scipy.fft import fft
import scipy.fftpack
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

excel_file_path = 'file.xlsx'
a1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

N = a1.size # data size
T = 1.0 / 100 # inverse of sampling rate
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)

y = a1.values
y= y - np.mean(y)
yf = np.abs(fft(y))
#xf = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(a1.size, d=T)
x = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(yf.size, 1 / 100)



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# ax.plot(np.abs(xf), np.abs(yf))
ax.plot(x[:x.size//2], abs(yf)[:yf.size//2])
plt.show()


link to the dataset:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/33mwe0esekdbfmlo0x8be/dataset.xlsx?rlkey=lq4frtwcja09iauwnifnt3o0u&st=bov1e0uy&dl=0

You can also do an FFT in Excel if you load the Analysis package. It is limited to 2^N lengths but that should be good enough to get an independent  feel for your data. Why did you expect anything other than a few random spikes? The spikes at 24,26,29,33 and 45 loo high and sharp enough to plausibly be real. Why not test your FFT implementation with a known signal and check that it gives the right answer?

Thank you @Martin. I have tried the same FFT with simple sinusoidal data it gives two major spikes. However, in my case, it is raw accelerometer data, so i do not understand whether to consider the spikes you mentioned are correct or not.

You may want to take a look at Short-time Fourier Transform (STFT). If the signal is not stationary, FFT will rarely will give you good insight.

the signal looks like noise to me. the only pattern is I see is in the envelope/amplitude. after sample ~1050, it quiets down. -- multiply by a window function. that might give better results. you're likely seeing "noise" in the spectrum too. nothing meaningful in the spectrum. because there is nothing meaningful in the signal.

A couple of hardware things to try. Deliberately inject mains hum by putting a wet finger on the ADC input and see if you can detect that. Also put the accelerometer on top of a small bag of damp sand (soil) and under some cotton wool to minimise vibrations and acoustic coupling. You would be surprised how sensitive these things can be.

@dankal44 I do not have proper knowledge about STFT, so whatever result I am getting , I am unable to interpret the result.

@Christoph Rackwitz, I tried applying Kalman filter to reduce the noise, however, the result are the same. i think I need to change the model of accelerometer and cross check it.

@SnehalShende Then gain the knowledge :) It is not rocket science and it may be very useful for you, even if not in this case.

STFT is just fourier transform on (possibly overlapping) pieces of the signal. you'll frequently (...) see spectrograms for audio and RF. that's how they are done.
